# Error creating shared library on Linux

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have created a Makefile for a C shared library. I tried using `-o` & `-fpic` flags after `shared` word. But I get the same error. I am not sure what is wrong with the makefile.

**MakeFile**

```
myProgram: main.o libmylib.so
    gcc -lm -o myProgram main.o -L. -lmylib

main.o: main.c
    gcc -O -c main.c main.h

addSorted.o: addSorted.c addSorted.h
    gcc -c -fpic addSorted.c

freeLinks.o: freeLinks.c freeLinks.h
    gcc -c -fpic freeLinks.c

libmylib.so: addSorted.o freeLinks.o
    gcc -shared libmylib.so addSorted.o freeLinks.o

all: myProgram
libs: libmylib.so

clean:
    rm -f myProgram *.o *.a *.gch
```

**Linux Terminal Error**

```
gcc -shared libmylib.so addSorted.o freeLinks.o
gcc: libmylib.so: No such file or directory
make: *** [libmylib.so] Error 1
```

Comment: I sense a `-o` is missing.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried with `-o` but I get the same error.

Comment: Somehow I'm finding that hard to imagine. post the terminal error *with it*, *in your question please*. In doing so, review [**Step #2 at this site**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html).

Comment: I have already done that. :)

Comment: `gcc -shared libmylib.so addSorted.o freeLinks.o` <=== no `-o` present.

Comment: Where did you add the `-o`?  You need: `gcc -shared -o libmylib.so addSorted.o freeLinks.o` — I imagine that wasn't what you tried, though.

Comment: I have written in my question that I have tried both the flags (`-o` & `-fpic`), but I get the same error

Comment: You'll do yourself a favour if you copy the attempt with `-o` and show the error output from that.  The other possibility is that `-shared` doesn't mean 'create a shared library' but means 'use shared libraries' (in preference to static libraries, and the `-static` option which means 'use static libraries in preference to shared libraries').  If this is the problem, you need to go and check the correct option for creating a shared library.

Comment: Note that the `-lm` option should go after the object files.  List object files before libraries when you're linking.  (When you're creating a shared library, other shared libraries go after the object files; the one you're creating needs to be specified separately, and that option and name can go anywhere as a pair of options.)

Comment: SCons actually makes this a lot easier.  http://www.scons.org/doc/1.1.0/HTML/scons-user/c593.html